# detecting angular brackets and removing them in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string variable with the following content-

```
<br/><p><http://google.com></p>
```

Iam using a C# program and I need to remove those angular brackets around the URL which means I want to modify that variable to get-

```
<br/><p>http://google.com</p>
```

Could someone please help me out? How can achieve that for any general expression?

Converting:

```
<br/><p><anythinghere></p>
```

TO

```
<br/><p>anythinghere</p>
```

Comment: What is with `<br/><p><p>anythinghere</p></p>`?

Comment: Why doesn't `<p>` fit `<anythinghere>`?

Comment: the string is being populated like that.. is there a way to remove the brackets?

Comment: are there <p> paragraphs on each side always? and every paragraph will have these brackets inside?

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking for any open node looking entities that have no closing counterpars, and that are not self-closing nodes. Then, you can just grab what is inside:

```
var elt = "<br/><p><anythinghere></p>";
var rxNoTag = new Regex(@"(?!/)<(([\w:.-]+)[^<>]*(?<!/))>(?!.*</\1>)");
var rst = rxNoTag.Replace(elt, "$1");
```

Output:

```
<br/><p>anythinghere</p>
```

Also, you can have a look and test at [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F!%2F)%3C((%5B%5Cw%3A.-%5D%2B)%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D*(%3F%3C!%2F))%3E(%3F!.*%3C%2F%5C1%3E)&i=%3Cbr%2F%3E%3Cp%3E%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%3E%3C%2Fp%3E&r=%241).

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer I feel I must ask some questions about the string. Is it user input? Is it being pulled from an html page or a data store? Is it coming to you as `<br/><p><http://google.com></p>` or are you wrapping `<http://google.com>`with `<br/><p></p>?` In the former case you could either use call `string.Replace` twice to remove the brackets first before you wrap it. If the latter is the case you're going to have some problems. I would say your best bet there, assuming you're always going to have a url in the form of `http://something.com` is to again use `string.Replace` to replace `<http://` with `http://` and `.com>` with `.com`. You could also probably use regex to accomplish this as well which could cover for multiple cases such as .org, .gov ,etc but I'm still a novice at regex so if you'd like to take that route I'd direct someone else to help you. You can, of course, cover multiple cases for extensions like .org or what have you by calling string.replace multiple times. I hope that points you in the right direction!